# Duplicate JasperReport with Detail band in same page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with JasperReport, I do not know how to propose the solution.

What I want is reflected in the images, since it is complicated to explain.

I have tried a second band of detail, groups, ... But nothing solves it to me.

The page is an A4 but it is divided in two with the same information.

Page 1:
[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85NzQ.png)

Page 2: 
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN2Lf.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You have 2 option fix the datasource so it duplicates data or post elaborate the report to copy the page to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this. The only solution is to adapt your data source.